# What is a good example of a program written using aspect-oriented techniques?

Tags: aop

I'm not necessarily looking for an example of code written on an AOP language, but some code that thoroughly and effectively divides into aspects, rather than components, so I could read it and see how to do it well.

Most of the examples of aspects I've seen are only a small part of the program (locking, logging); I don't think I've ever seen a complete semi-non-trivial program that was primarily divided along aspects.

Anyone know some good ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Spring Roo](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/architecture.html) uses aspects quite a bit. IMO finding open-source AOP code is relatively uncommon, though; most of it I've seen IRL is embedded into closed-source, internal code.

There are a few books that discuss AOP application/architecture design which I found pretty interesting, and there are a fair number of papers that discuss non-canonical uses.